# ScrollViewer should keep relations and fill its Container

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store app with a `Hub` page. On one `HubSection` i show a `Image`.
The Image should be Zoomable so i add a `ScrollViewer` and set `ZoomMode` to `Enabled`.

But now the `Image` is not scaled to the height of the `Hub` anymore. (It uses the size of the Bitmap)
If i remove the `ScrollViewer` the `Image` is scaled to the current Height and keeps the Height/Width ratio.

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Source="{Binding Image1}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

How can i get the `ScrollViewer` to Fill my Parent? (`VerticalAlignment` does not work)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled, in that way the image height has to fit the height of the hub control.

Comment: Yes that does Work but now if i Zoom into it i cann't scroll vertically anymore.